# a question on measurability

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $X$ be a compact metric space and $(\Omega, F, P)$ a nonatomic probability space. Suppose that $(\Omega, F', P')$ is the completion of $(\Omega, F, P)$.

If $f: \Omega \rightarrow X$ is a $F'$-measurable, does there exist a $F$-measurable function $g$ such that $g=f$ a.e.?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a sketch of one approach: If $f$ is *simple*, i.e., only takes finitely many values,  then the result is easy.
In general, let $f_n$ be a sequence of simple $F^\prime$-measurable functions that 
converge to $f$ everywhere. Let $g_n$ be a sequence of $F$-measurable functions so that 
 $P^\prime(f_n\neq g_n)=0$ for every $n$. Fix an arbitrary $x\in X$ and let $C$ be the $F$-measurable set $\{\omega: g_n(\omega)\mbox{ is Cauchy }\}$. Now set 
$$g(\omega)=\cases{\lim_n g_n(\omega)&$\omega\in C$ \cr x&otherwise.}$$
You can check that $g$ is $F$-measurable and $P^\prime(f\neq g)=0$.